# Tomcat problem redeploying:

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

In the catalina log file we see this error message in some cases when the web application are tried to be redeployed:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive ROOT.war
13-May-2009 09:50:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext processTlds
SEVERE: Error reading tld listeners java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:340)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.getJarPaths(TldConfig.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.processTlds(StandardContext.java:4441)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:829)
```

It looks like the application is re-deployed due to the fact that the NAS (network attached storage) is temporarily not accessible. It could be that authority means "cannot access' but I like to understand the reason and the message.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like it has something to do with a [.tld file](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html) in a JAR somewhere containing an badly formatted [URI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html). Check the contents of the JARs in the app you are re-deploying.

(Also why are you re-deploying ROOT?)

Comment: we're not actively redeploying ROOT.war, Tomcat has decided to do that. All code is on a NAS and we think there are issues with the connection to it. Unfortunately we do not administer the machine so difficult to debug.

Comment: Well, Tomcat will re-deploy an app automatically if it detects changes to it's web.xml (I think there are some other conditions too). I think that might cause some pretty strange problems if the appBase or docBase is on a NAS and the connection gets dropped - I'm not sure if that's really a good way to have it configured.

Comment: I agree with you that it is not a good way but we were forced to... We have changed the deploying properties and since then a number of issues have disappeared...
The error message however is still there but does not seem to do any harm sofar.